# How do I declare multi-dimensional arrays or structures in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this structure in PHP and I'm not really sure how to translate it into Java, I need to mention that all keys and values are strings.

For bonus points, please show an example

```
private $group = array(
     "group1" = array("item1","item2"),
     "group2" = array("item3","item4"),
     ....
     "groupn" = array("itemn","itemn+1"),
     ....
);
```

Comment: `bonus points`??? We are not selling out code here. Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: Have a look at the example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ArrayOfstringArrays.htm

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with a List of Lists in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Map<String, List<String>> group = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
   group.put("group1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2")));
   group.put("group2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("item3", "item4")));
```

In php, if you iterate over the elements with a foreach

```
foreach ($group as $key => $subarray)
```

You're guaranteed the first $key is 'group1' because a php array is implicitly order by key creation time. If you want the same guarantee in java you must use `LinkedHashMap`. Otherwise a regular `HashMap` is fine.

Comment: thanks , i've learned something new today

Answer (score 1):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Java uses the true definition of an array. What you want is a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("item1");
list.add("item2");
map.add("group1", list);
```

And so on...

Comment: Don't instantiate using `HashMap` but `Map`! Similarly, values should be `List` and not `ArrayList`. Don't use implementations where you can use an interface.

Comment: I don't see why not if this list will only be used in one method. If you are passing it all over the place, then yes, maybe...

Comment: Simply because you should preferably use interfaces instead of concrete implementations. With your code, you are condemned to use hashmaps and arraylists. Which means you cannot use any other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Collection<String>>`. If values in the collection are unique, use a `Set`, otherwise a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` as your solution :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("group1", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
```

etc...

Comment: Values of the map should be `List<String>`, not ArrayList.