# Add elements in multidimensional ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to store some values (actually a message) using list in Java. I want to store something like:

```
{user1, message, user2, time}
{user1, message, user4, time}
{user3, message, user1, time}
```

I have declared an arraylist like this:

```
public List<List<String>> message = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

How can I add values in this list and how can I get a specific row (let's say the second row) of this list?

I've tried:

```
    message.get(0).add(msg, target,time);
```

but I get an error:

> "The method add(String) in the type List is not applicable for
>   the arguments (String, String, Integer)"

Comment: Please see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java) which your question duplicates.

Comment: "*but I get an error*" what does error massage say?

Comment: The error is "The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, Integer)

Comment: @Galil It would be better to put information in your original post instead of of comment. This info is important and people who are reading your question shouldn't be forced to search for it in comments. You can do it wish [[edit]] option placed under your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();        
Object[] ob = new Object[4];
ob[0] = "user1";
ob[1] = "messge1";
ob[2] = "user2";
ob[3] = "time1";

list.add(ob);       

ob = new Object[4];
ob[0] = "user2";
ob[1] = "messge2";
ob[2] = "user4";
ob[3] = "time2";
list.add(ob);

// Output the values
for(Object[] o : list){
    System.out.print(o[0] + "\t");
    System.out.print(o[1] + "\t");
    System.out.print(o[2] + "\t");
    System.out.print(o[3] + "\n");
}
```

and the output will be:

```
user1 messge1 user2 time1

user2 messge2 user4 time2
```

Comment: I think this is almost what I'm looking for, but could you please tell me how can I get a specific value (eg message1) without the for-loop if possible. Moreover, how can I delete a specific row?

Comment: (list.get(0))[3] // returns time  AND  list.remove(0); removes the first {user1,msg,user2,time} record.

Answer (score 0):

by

```
message.get(0);
```

you are retriving the first list in list of list referred by `message`

`List` has `add(T object)` method so you can't pass all 3 Objects in one call, one way to do is

```
message.get(0).add(msg);
message.get(0).add(target);
message.get(0).add(time);
```