# Getting out of memory exception while creating 2 Dimensional int array

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have:

```
int [][] lengths=null;
```

I have to initialize this based on runtime parameter.

I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` when my array size something like `int[13000][130000]` or more.

Is there a way to come around this or any other approach I can take ?

Comment: Increase the heap size. 

 Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm

Comment: What is the Heap size? Arrays need contiguous memory so JVM might not be in position to allocate 13000*130000*32 byte (memory required to store an int in java) for this array. So, it threw OutofMemoryException. First thing is to check whether this huge array is required and if it is required increase the JVM heap.

Comment: You will need 13000*130000*4 bytes to store your array ( if you did not forget a 0 in your 1st number), that's about 6.3Gb, you will need more to let the rest of your program work. I'm afraid increasing the memory of your JVM will not be enough, what is the purpose of having such a big array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** this should not prevent the `OutOfMemoryError` but you need to learn about the `JVM` memory arguments, because it should help for any case.

You need to take a look at the `JVM` memory parameters. actually you can set the as much memory as you want to your `JVM` :

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
```

and you may want to check this parameters also.

```
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this could be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this could be 40% from your Xmx value
```

also you may tell you `JVM` what type of `GC` to use like (i think its already use by default in the earlier versions)

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't absolutely neccessary for you to fill every single cell of this grid, [nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474969/1654827) might be a smarter approach. Think of it as an 1D-array filled with 1D-arrays of various size. As a data type, they are especially useful for values provided during runtime, so if you don't want to or are not allowed to increase your mem cap as described in Salahs answer, think of this as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

An integer takes 4 byte of memory. You want to allocate `4 Byte * 13000 * 130000 = 6760000000 Byte`. That are ~6,5 gigabyte of memory.

If your computer has that amount of memory, there exist JVM parameters to increase the maximum used by the JVM.