# How to use Collections or Sets to organize data structures inside data structures in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, set

I have several lists of entity names which compose a dataset that is organized, for example:

- ENT_01
- ENT_02
- ...
- ENT_nn

Being any number of lists of different entity names (as Strings) always numbered from **01** to **nn**.

What I intend to do is read them, and create some data structure that utilizes the entity root name (ex. ENT) and associate each instance of it (ex. ENT_01, ENT_02) to itself. Meaning that when I call **ENT** I could use it (or its position in a List, ArrayList, etc) as a parameter to retriveve de whole numbered structure. Problem being, I also need a way to easily access each numbered entity instances.

I thought about and tried based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java) to implement an **"ArrayList of ArrayLists"**, with the first being the rootname and the second containing the instances, but it looked inefficient and improvised way to do it.

Is there any structure or class, maybe under **Collections** and/or **Sets**, in Java which would do it in a more elegant and effcient way?

Comment: `ENT_01` ... `ENT_nn` is `String` or `Object` or.. array of objects `Ent[]`.. What is it?

Comment: Sorry, the ENT_01 actually have a proprietary extension, but it will be entered as String and treated further down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing how exactly your data looks like and it might be a little too much for SO.

However, assuming "ENT" would be some arbitrary key (I'll assume it is a string) you could use a `Map<String, Entity>` where `Entity` would be a class that contains your inner structure(s).

Example:

```
Map<String, Entity> entities = ...;
```

Further assuming that the inner elements 0 to n are densely packed (i.e. there are no or only small holes) you could use an `ArrayList` (assigned to a `List` property) and use the `get(index)` method to access the element at that index.

Example:

```
class Entity {
  List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

  Element getElement( int index ) {
    if( index < 0 || index >= elements.size() ) {
      return null; //out of range, i.e. no such element
    }

    return elements.get(index);
  } 
}
```

Hence a lookup for element "ENT_02" could look like this:

```
//note that you'd need to handle "ENT" not being present, i.e. the get() returning null
entities.get( "ENT" ).getElement( 2 );
```

If your structure is as simple you could actually just make it a `Map<String, List<Element>>` but I'd assume that it isn't that simple or won't stay that way (i.e. `Entity` will probably contain more than just the list of elements).