# Instantiating List of Lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to solve a leetcode problem where I have a function and I am supposed to return a List of a List. 
eg. public     List < List < Integer>> func(TreeNode root)

To solve this problem, I wish to create another function where I pass an empty List of List and eventually return this List of List as my answer.

```
List < List < Integer >> ret = new List < List < Integer >>();
```

However this leads to an error, List is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

If I change this to

```
ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer >> ret = new ArrayList < ArrayList <Integer > >();
```

I cannot convert the `ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer > to List < List < Integer > >`.

I can't even get this to work.

```
List < List < Integer > > ret = new ArrayList < ArrayList < Integer > > ();
```

Can you suggest some way around this? I have been facing this kind of issue a lot of times and usually find some workaround to solve this. What is the proper method to resolve this?

Comment: `List < List < Integer > > ret = new ArrayList < List < Integer > > ()`

Comment: It might sound rude but stop coding at leetcode and learn your language. Learn what is the difference between class, abstract class and interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with a List of Lists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java)

Comment: Even though a `ArrayList<Integer>` is a `List<Integer>`, a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is *not* a `List<List<Integer>>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po.

Answer (score 2):

Only at instantiation do you need the concrete class.  This should work

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which is shorthand for

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```