# Create list of lists

Tags: java, android, list

How can I create list that contain lists and each has multiple strings.

```
mylist = [['example01','example02','example03'],[example1','example2','example3'], [example4','example5','example6']]
```

So when I do "for each" still get list file?

Tried like without luck:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(("Hello","You"),("World","Power"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with a List of Lists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
List<List<String>> messages = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Hello","You"), Arrays.asList("World","Power"));
```